# Render Nested JSON as Form Inputs in Vue Template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue component that is passed JSON data as a prop. The schema changes depending on the type of the object—the component is generic—and some of the JSON has nested objects/arrays.

*The data*:

```
"check": {
    "id": "d5d1d763236f3",
    "created_on": "2016-08-05T15:49:18.263399Z",
    "type": "A",
    "header": {
      "Host": ["appname.com"]
    },
    "method": "GET"
}
```

*The template*

```
  <div class="results" v-if="type">
  <table v-for="item in type">
  <tbody>
  <tr v-for="(key, val) in item">
    <td>{{ key }}</td>
    <td><input v-model="val" type="text"/></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Is there a sensible way to dynamically check whether `val` is of an Object or Array, and if so, recurse over it? It's important to also retain the binding so that the state is updated when those nested fields change (so we can HTTP PATCH any edits).

e.g. `function iterate(obj)` that can render the nested object. JS is not my strong suite, and `isEnumerable` or `hasOwnProperty('length')` seem to be fragile.